# Stack overflow issue in rust when making a simple VM

Tags: rust, virtual-machine, project, rust-cargo

I have come to you guys today with an error I cannot seem to fix sadly.

First let me explain what I'm trying to do. I am writing a little VM in Rust. I have just finished writing the bare minimum for the VM as you can tell by how unfinished the code is. I have made a system where you can load the program into a certain spot in memory so you can jump to that spot for subroutines later on. The run function in the Arcate struct runs whatever operation is on 0x0000.

As you can also see I have gone with using a databuss just so I can use external memory devices like creating another ArcateMemory struct as a different "drive".

It seems I am getting a stack overflow but since Rust has the best stack overflow messages all I am getting is that it is in main.

Thanks again for your help. Sorry if it is a stupid mistake I'm a little new to Rust.

main.rs

```rust
#![allow(dead_code)]

type Instr = u8;
type Program = Vec<Instr>;
#[derive(PartialEq, Eq)]
enum Signals {
    BusWrite,
    BusRead,
    ErrNoInstruction,
    Success,
    Halt,
}

struct Arcate {
    mem : ArcateMem,
    ci: Instr,
    pc: i32,
    acr: i32,
    gp1: i32,
    gp2: i32,
    gp3: i32,
    gp4: i32,
    gp5: i32,
    gp6: i32,
    gp7: i32,
    gp8: i32,
}

impl Arcate {
    fn new(memory: ArcateMem) -> Self {
        Arcate {
            mem: memory,
            ci: 0,
            pc: 0,
            acr: 0,
            gp1: 0,
            gp2: 0,
            gp3: 0,
            gp4: 0,
            gp5: 0,
            gp6: 0,
            gp7: 0,
            gp8: 0,
        }
    }
    fn fetchi(&mut self) {
        let i: Instr = ArcateBus {data: 0, addr: self.pc, todo: Signals::BusRead, mem: self.mem}.exec();
        self.ci = i;
        self.pc += 1;
    }
    fn fetcha(&mut self) -> Instr{
        let i: Instr = ArcateBus {data: 0, addr: self.pc, todo: Signals::BusRead, mem: self.mem}.exec();
        self.pc += 1;
        i
    }
    fn getr(&mut self, reg: Instr) -> i32 {
        match reg {
            0x01 => { self.ci as i32},
            0x02 => { self.pc  },
            0x03 => { self.acr },
            0x04 => { self.gp1 },
            0x05 => { self.gp2 },
            0x06 => { self.gp3 },
            0x07 => { self.gp4 },
            0x08 => { self.gp5 },
            0x09 => { self.gp6 },
            0x0a => { self.gp7 },
            0x0b => { self.gp8 },
            _    => { panic!("Register not found {}", reg) }
        }
    }
    fn setr(&mut self, reg: Instr, val: i32) {
        match reg {
            0x01 => { self.ci  = val as u8 },
            0x02 => { self.pc  = val },
            0x03 => { self.acr = val },
            0x04 => { self.gp1 = val },
            0x05 => { self.gp2 = val },
            0x06 => { self.gp3 = val },
            0x07 => { self.gp4 = val },
            0x08 => { self.gp5 = val },
            0x09 => { self.gp6 = val },
            0x0a => { self.gp7 = val },
            0x0b => { self.gp8 = val },
            _    => { panic!("Register not found {}", reg) }
        }
    }
    fn dbg(&mut self, regs: bool, mem: bool) {
        if regs {
            println!("ci : {}", self.ci );
            println!("pc : {}", self.pc );
            println!("acr: {}", self.acr);
            println!("gp1: {}", self.gp1);
            println!("gp2: {}", self.gp2);
            println!("gp3: {}", self.gp3);
            println!("gp4: {}", self.gp4);
            println!("gp5: {}", self.gp5);
            println!("gp6: {}", self.gp6);
            println!("gp7: {}", self.gp7);
            println!("gp8: {}\n", self.gp8);
        }
    }
    fn exec(&mut self) -> Signals {
        match self.ci {
            // 01: 2 args. movir imm, reg
            0x01 => {
                let imm1 = self.fetcha();
                let imm2 = self.fetcha();
                let imm  = ((imm1 as i32) << 8) + imm2 as i32;
                let reg  = self.fetcha();
                self.setr(reg, imm);
                Signals::Success
            }
            // 02: 2 args. movrr reg, reg
            0x02 => {
                let regf = self.fetcha();
                let regt = self.fetcha();
                let regv = self.getr(regf);
                self.setr(regt, regv);
                Signals::Success
            }
            // 03: 2 args. movrm reg, mem
            // 04: 2 args. movim imm, mem
            // 05: 2 args. addrr reg, reg
            0x05 => {
                let rego = self.fetcha();
                let regt = self.fetcha();
                let regov = self.getr(rego);
                let regtv = self.getr(regt);
                self.acr = regov + regtv;
                Signals::Success
            }
            // 06: 2 args. addir imm, reg
            // ff: 0 args. halt
            0xff => {
                Signals::Halt
            }
            _ => {
                Signals::ErrNoInstruction
            }

        }
        
    }
    fn load(&mut self, prog: Program, loc: usize) {
        let mut ld = 0;
        for i in loc..prog.len() {
            self.mem.mem[i] = prog[ld];
            println!("{:2x} -> {:12x}", prog[ld], i);
            ld += 1;
        }
    }
    fn run(&mut self, dbgR: bool) {
        let mut sig: Signals = Signals::Success;
        self.dbg(dbgR, false);
        while sig == Signals::Success {
            self.fetchi();
            sig = self.exec();
            self.dbg(dbgR, false);
        }
    }
}
struct ArcateBus {
    data: Instr,
    addr: i32,
    todo: Signals,
    mem : ArcateMem,
}
impl ArcateBus {
    fn exec(&mut self) -> Instr {
        if self.todo == Signals::BusWrite {
            self.mem.mem[self.addr as usize] = self.data;
            0x00
        } else if self.todo == Signals::BusRead {
            self.mem.mem[self.addr as usize]
        }else {
            0xFF
        }
    }
}

#[derive(Copy, Clone)]
struct ArcateMem {
    mem: [Instr; 0xFFFF*0xFFFF],
}

impl ArcateMem {
    fn new() -> Self {
        ArcateMem {
            mem: [0; 0xFFFF*0xFFFF],
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mem: ArcateMem = ArcateMem::new();
    let mut arc: Arcate = Arcate::new(mem);
    let prog = vec![
        0x01, 0xfe, 0xfe, 0x04,
        0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x05,
        0x05, 0x04, 0x05,
        0xff,
    ];
    arc.load(prog, 0x0000);
    arc.run(true);

}
```

Comment: Don't edit your question to make it ask something different from the original question. If you have a follow up question or anything else different, post a new question. I've rolled your edit back to the original quesiton.

Answer (score 2):

I think the issue is around `ArcateMem`, you are allocating 0xFFFF*0xFFFF `Instr`, which is about 4GB. With the way the code is written right now, you are allocating this on the stack, which generally can't support allocations this large. You'll probably want to use `Box<>` to allocate your memory in the heap, as it is more likely able to deal with allocations this large.

It's possible you could configure your operating system to increase your stack size, but I'd recommend using the heap.

Comment: Ah alright. Im not sure how to use ``Box<>`` mind if i get an example. Im a newbie with Rust lol.

Comment: The [official Rust book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch15-01-box.html) and [rust by example](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/rust-by-example/std/box.html) are good places to learn more!

Comment: I just tried out what it said. I changed it to ``mem: Box<[Instr; 0xFFFF*0xFFFF]>`` and also changed the initializer to ``mem: Box::new([0; 0xFFFF*0xFFFF]),`` the only issue im getting now is that it seems Copy is not implemented for this. Any tips?

Comment: It's not possible to automatically derive the `Copy` trait for structs that contain a box (This is an intentional choice by the language designers, because it's not obvious what should happen. Should the data in the Box also be duplicated? Or something else?). This compiler error uncovers what I suspect is a deeper logic error in your program. Do you really want to be making copies of your `ArcateMem`? I suspect you probably don't. You likely want to be taking mutable references to your allocated memory.

Comment: Alright. Ive made progress. I realized i could just use clone() on the fetch functions. Issue is, im still getting a stack overflow.

Comment: How would i take a mutable reference? I was trying to but it just wont work.

Comment: Stack overflow isn't really the best forum for general help like this. You might want to spend a little more time with the Rust book and playing with [smaller examples](https://github.com/rust-lang/rustlings) to improve your understanding of the language mechanics.

Comment: Because Rust doesn't (yet) have [placement by return](https://github.com/PoignardAzur/placement-by-return/blob/placement-by-return/text/0000-placement-by-return.md) (RFC proposed but not yet accepted), `Box([0; 0xFFFF*0xFFFF])` still allocates on the stack and then copies into the box.  You should probably allocate via a `Vec` instead, and then convert [`into_boxed_slice`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.into_boxed_slice).