# Why my safe rust code triggers segmentation fault?

Tags: rust

My safe rust code is listed below:

```rust
use std::mem::size_of;

const ROWS_PER_PAGE: usize = PAGE_SIZE / ROW_SIZE;
const TABLE_MAX_ROWS: usize = TABLE_MAX_PAGES * ROWS_PER_PAGE;
const ROW_SIZE: usize = ID_SIZE + USERNAME_SIZE + EMAIL_SIZE;
const TABLE_MAX_PAGES: usize = 100;
const PAGE_SIZE: usize = 4096;
const ID_SIZE: usize = size_of::<u64>();
const USERNAME_SIZE: usize = 32;
const EMAIL_SIZE: usize = 255;

#[derive(Clone, Copy, Debug)]
pub struct Page {
    buffer: [u8; PAGE_SIZE],
}
pub struct Table {
    pub pages: [Option<Page>; TABLE_MAX_ROWS],
    pub num_rows: usize,
}

impl Table {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        Self {
            pages: [None; TABLE_MAX_ROWS],
            num_rows: 0,
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    println!("{}", ROW_SIZE);
    let table = Table::new();
    println!("{:p}", &table);
}
```

Every line in the piece seems like ordinary, but on my MacBook Pro it crashed with 'Segmentation fault'.

```bash
$ cargo r
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.07s
    Running `target/debug/segfault`
295
[1]    68684 segmentation fault 
$ rustup show  active-toolchain       
nightly-aarch64-apple-darwin (default)
```

Stranger still, when I copy-paste the code piece into [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=e9938b669c927b70a10f3a07f2fbdbf7), It said 'Stack overflow'. Where is the cause?

```bash
   Compiling playground v0.0.1 (/playground)
   Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.82s
   Running `target/debug/playground`

thread 'main' has overflowed its stack
fatal runtime error: stack overflow
timeout: the monitored command dumped core
/playground/tools/entrypoint.sh: line 11:     8 Aborted                 timeout --signal=KILL ${timeout} "$@"
```

Comment: Not sure why you have the `c++` tag - because of that, I found the question and wasted some of my time. Others may do the same, unless you remove the tag.

Comment: @Adrian Mole sorry for that. I will remove the tag.

Comment: After doing some math, `ROW_SIZE = 8 + 32 + 255 = 295`, and 295 is in your output so that's not the issue.

Comment: Your code is trying to place large structures on the stack, and the stack isn't large enough. The solution is to create your structures in the heap

Comment: @Jon It seems like the cause, default rust stack limitation is 2MiB.

Comment: Possibly dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70816744/rust-thread-main-has-overflowed-its-stack or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69715558/stack-overflow-issue-in-rust-when-making-a-simple-vm

Answer (score 3):

Your `Table` struct is over 5 MB large (`TABLE_MAX_ROWS` is 1300, `Page` is 4096 bytes large, so `Option<Page>` is 4097 bytes, so total size is 5326100 bytes plus 8 for `num_rows`).

You try to allocate one on the stack. You can't do that, the stack isn't this large. The segmentation fault you get is the attempt to access beyond the bounds of the stack.

You'll want to put some of that on the heap. Probably all of it, though beware that it can be a bit tricky in Rust to create a huge object on the heap (especially in debug mode, the compiler might want to create it on the stack first and copy it over).

Comment: Could you elaborate on that last point? I believe I'm having that issue because allocating a huge array with `Box::new([0; 921600])` is still causing a segfault.

Comment: @CosimosCendo See https://users.rust-lang.org/t/why-does-putting-an-array-in-a-box-cause-stack-overflow/36493/19 and https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/53827

Answer (score 3):

The playground error is actually describing the same problem as the error from MacOS, but more specifically - the "stack", the memory space reserved for function-local variables that are not `static` (namely, `table`) has been filed up. This results in a segfault because the program tries to use more memory regardless, and so steps into pages it doesn't have access to. The OS limits how large the stack can be to much smaller than the total memory capacity, often as little as 1MB, although this is configurable.

So `table` is allocated on the stack because it is a local variable of `main`. `table` in turn is so huge because each `Option<Page>` (i.e. a flag denoting whether it is present, followed by a whole `Page`) within the array is laid out directly next to each other in memory, with no indirection or separate allocations as you might be used to in other languages. Within `Page`, all 4096 `u8`s are contiguous, and all of the ~1400 (if I did the math right) `Page`s are contiguous in `Table`, which means that when you construct a `Table`, the resulting value is (slightly over) 1400*4096 = 5.46MB of contiguous data. Which you then try to put in a memory region (the stack) much too small for it.

To get around this, you can use `Box<Table>` instead so that the table's data is instead allocated on the heap, which is allowed to grow basically as large as hardware permits. You may also have to compile your program with `--release`, because otherwise the table will temporarily exist on the stack when you construct it before placing it in the box, which causes the same problem.

That said, your `Table` looks suspiciously like it's supposed to be a dynamically-sized array of `Page`s, in which case you can simply use `Vec<Page>` which will not only do the same thing, but avoids the problem entirely because `Vec` puts its items on the heap implicitly.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your code is trying to put too much data on the stack, causing the stack to overflow. On some platforms a stack overflow will cause a segmentation fault.

The solution is to put the data on the heap:

```rust
pub struct Table {
    pub pages: Vec<Option<Page>>,
    pub num_rows: usize,
}

impl Table {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        Self {
            pages: vec![None; TABLE_MAX_ROWS],
            num_rows: 0,
        }
    }
}
```

With this change, the [code runs in the playgound](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=b9f287ae4665af29e32b23461b9b1c2b).